# How to put variable inside two curly braces in string

Tags: python, string, format

I am stuck.
On https://developer.storeautomator.com/#9ce3d126-f868-4d0a-94d2-d8b9bb2fb5a7 for python they have

> url = "https://data.storeautomator.com/api/v3/products"
> payload={}
> headers = {
> 'authorization': `'{{AccessToken}}'`}

I have to put my AccessToken value instead of {{AccessToken}}. I've tried it all but always get "Access denied". I feel like I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using triple curly braces. `{{` gets converted to a string `{` (It is an escape sequence).

```
AccessToken = "AccessTokenValue"
payload={}
headers = { 'authorization': f'{{{AccessToken}}}'}
print(headers)
```

This will print: `{'authorization': '{AccessTokenValue}'}`